# Is it appropriate to post an small audio clip, and ask for transcripts ?

Tags: discussion, question-quality

I want to post a 10s audio clip that was cut from some movie, which I can only understand/hear part of it, to ask someone else to get a transcript of that ?

Will such a question get closed ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Generally, no, asking to transcribe an audio clip is not acceptable, because it cannot be searched for. Questions on Stack Exchange are expected to have lasting value; someone who has the same question must have a chance of finding the existing question.

If the audio clip is sourced precisely (with the name of the movie, the character who's speaking, and a precise description of when this happens in the movie), then it's ok, because someone else having trouble understanding the same passage movie can search for the name of the movie and the character.

The same goes for a song or any other audio material: yes, if it's a published work and you give references that can be searched for. No, if it's some private recording or a sound byte of unknown origin.

Comment: If it's a private recording or of unknown origin, you can ask on the chat, probably someone will be kind enough to provide you with a transcript.